# What is the HeavyUsage charge on AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What are below cost charges in AWS Cost Explorer

```
<region-code>-HeavyUsage:dynamodb.write
<region-code>-HeavyUsage:dynamodb.read
```

Didnot find any documentation about Dynamodb bill/cost explanation. The [related doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/detailed-billing.html) I found is for EC2 - HeavyUsage.

Any info on what these charges are in DynamoDB?

Note: We do not have any Reserved Capacity in any of the regions.

Answer (score 1):

This is for provisioned throughput capacity you bought for DynamoDB.  See [Amazon DynamoDB reservations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/cost-optimization-reservation-models/amazon-dynamodb-reservations.html)